# Processing script fails to run as javascript

Tags: processing, processing.js

A relatively simple Processing script fails in both the 2.0 IDE's Javascript mode and in browsers (via Processing.JS) for reason unknown. I'm pretty sure the same problem is stopping both methods. I've isolated a line that causes the failure and illustrated in the following pages:

- [Test1.html](http://test.geotheory.co.uk/Test1.html) is a cut-down version of the project script that works
- [Test2.html](http://test.geotheory.co.uk/Test2.html) demonstrates how Test1 fails when a single extra command is called (line 93), although it works fine in IDE's Java mode. The offending line only seeks to re-print info that was already successfully printed in `void setup(){}`, hence my confusion.

All scripts are viewable [here](http://test.geotheory.co.uk/) but the key line in [Test2.pde](http://test.geotheory.co.uk/Test2.pde) is in `void drawLinks()`.

Any idea what is causing this?  I've wasted so many hours on this now!  Its possible to just copy/paste the [Test2.pde script](http://test.geotheory.co.uk/Test2.pde) into a new Processing 2.0 IDE to play around with it in Java and Javascript modes..

Comment: Forgive my lack of familiarily with Processing, but this is not valid JavaScript. How exactly are you trying to run this in Chrome? Exactly what error are you getting in the browser's console?

Comment: Try ProcessingJS. I at least feel that ProcessingJS gives a better, more embedded feeling when presenting Processing.

Comment: Please see the updated section in the question above. I've changed to ProcessingJS and provided examples.

Comment: Just above where you get the problem you use some new for-loop notation, try changing this for the more traditional iteration over ArrayList. So instead of (N el:al) try using an iterator Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
//dosomething
}

Comment: Nice idea olovholm but sadly no luck. See http://test1.geotheory.co.uk/Test3.html and its code (http://test1.geotheory.co.uk/Test3.pde). This method did work in Java mode however.

Comment: I had a look at the ProcessingJS page and seems like they do iteration this way:  for (int i = balls.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) { 

    // An ArrayList doesn't know what it is storing so we have 

    // to cast the object coming out

    Ball ball = (Ball) balls.get(i);

    ball.move();

    ball.display();

    if (ball.finished()) {

      // Items can be deleted with remove()

      balls.remove(i);

    }

I find processing and web a bit tricky since I don't know which libraries that are accessible. By the way, do you have any idea where the problem might be. What does the command line tell?

Comment: Apologies for delay responding. There doesn't appear to be any problem with the iteration. For instance if I change the print command nested in the loop from 'println(l.linkid);' (i.e. print the ID integer of the object) to 'println(l);' (print the whole object) the code works ok, and prints "[Object object]". But when variable '.linkid' is specified the code fails. The underlying data certainly is there (prints in java mode), it just seems that javascript mode is unable to access it. I've just tried creating a new object 'Link i = l' and printing that instead but no luck :(

Comment: I've created 2 new scripts to clarify the problem, which I've now confirmed is arising because javascript cannot access data held in an arraylist within an object. The first shows a working script (that uses a simple array). The second fails because it uses an arraylist. http://test1.geotheory.co.uk/script1_works.html http://test1.geotheory.co.uk/script2_fails.html

Comment: Hi! Glad it worked out. It's quite hard finding those problems. Glad Petros found out the bug exactly! Best of luck on the program. Following your blog! Interesting stuff. Please have a look at lovholm.net, not so much geo, but something in the same street.

Comment: Thanks olov. The app is at http://networkpathfinder.geotheory.co.uk/. Blog is currently in the process of dying and I'm about to move to geotheory.co.uk. I'll check you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with ProcessingJS's version of ArrayList. While it is [specified properly](http://processingjs.org/reference/ArrayList/) there seems to be a bug with the constructor that accepts an initialCapacity in it. A quite recent bug report [also shows this](https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1917-arraylist-constructor-capacity-mis-interpreted-as-size-breaks-indexed-access).

tl;dr: Remove the variable n from the creation of the arrayList in line 65,

```
this.links = new ArrayList<Link>(n);
```

should become:

```
this.links = new ArrayList<Link>();
```

Comment: Hurray!! That was it. I've always included the initialCapacity specification as I understood it optimises memory usage. Thanks Petros (fellow Bartlett grad) you get the bounty :)

Comment: As additional comment on this: the whole idea of the ArrayList container is that it's dynamically sized. There is no reason to ever construct it with an initial size argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you have created the code in the Processing IDE it can't directly be used in a web browser, to run the script in a web browser you have mainly two options:

A) You can export a java-applet from Processing. This can then later be embedded into your webpage. This treats the file as a java-applet so even though it works, it's not perhaps the elegant solution.

B) ProcessingJS is reading processing files and run them as native javascript in the web browser. You download the JS library and makes a file to import this and point to the Processing source file, this is then parsed and drawn in native javascript.

Comment: Please see the updated section in the question above. I've changed to ProcessingJS and provided examples.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when using OOP with processing.js you must prepend all instance variables with a `this.` in order for it to work correctly, especially when such objects are instantiated within an `array` or an `ArrayList`. You will need to make this modification to all constructors and methods.

For example:

```
class Route {
  ArrayList<Integer> cities;
  float distance;

  Route(ArrayList CITIES, float DISTANCE) {
    this.cities = CITIES;
    this.distance = DISTANCE;
  }
}
```

For a live example, check out the [.pde linked](http://www.resume.jamesjamesjames.com/work_history_timeline.pde) in the source of my [interactive resume](http://www.resume.jamesjamesjames.com/).

The modified code will still execute in Processing : Java / Standard Mode but becomes excessively wordy. I usually only make this change if I am porting a project to processing.js or wanting to have a project that works in both Standard / Java and JavaScript (processing.js) modes.

Comment: Please see the updated section in the question above. I've changed to ProcessingJS and provided examples. The 'this.' tip does not seem to resolve anything.